# App Crash when opening Database in Iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am using FMDB APIS to use database in my project using the following link:https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

in the First Step i Create and object of FMDatabase and get the DB linked:

```
FMDatabase *dbObject = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
```

Now I open the Database using the following code:

```
 if (![dbObject open]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not Open Database");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Database Opened!");
    [dbObject executeUpdate:@"create table user(id integer primary key autoincrement, f_name text, l_name text, session_id text)"];
    [dbObject close];
}
```

Now i want to write the data On Clik of button from fields. i Write the following code:

```
if (![dbObject open]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not Open Database");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Database Opened!");
    [dbObject executeUpdate:@"insert into user(f_name, l_name, session_id) values(?,?,?)",loginObject.fName, loginObject.lName, loginObject.sessionId,nil];
    [dbObject close];
}
```

Now when i reopen the DB here. in the same view controller. it gives me the following error. 
please note First time its opening the Database and next times its not. I dont know whats the problem. Please guide.

the Error i got is:

```
[NSCFString open]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e21630
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're not retaining `dbObject` at some point. The error message says that you're sending the `open` message to an instance of `NSString`. This means that the memory that used to contain your `FMDatabase` object is now ocupied by a string.

Comment: If you have the value in a property (you don't in the code above), then it should be set to `retain` and you should assign to it with the `self.dbObject = ...` notation.